# JPA - Invoking stored procedure with BLOB parameter

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, blob

I'm working with JPA 2.0. I would like to invoke an Oracle stored procedure. One of the parameters is a BLOB.

```
PROCEDURE test(file IN BLOB);
```

I'm trying to invoke it with the next code:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("{ CALL test(?) }");
query.setParameter(1, bytes);
query.executeUpdate();
```

I'm getting the next error:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'test'

The problem is how to pass a blob parameter because I'm able to invoke other stored procedures without blob parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void insertData(DataSource ds, byte[] data) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;

    try {
        conn = ds.getConnection();

        cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call test (?)}");
        Blob blob = conn.createBlob();
        blob.setBytes(1, data);

        cstmt.setBlob(1, blob);

        cstmt.execute();
    } finally {
        if (cstmt != null) {
            cstmt.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your JDBC solution, but I would like to do it using JPA framework.

Comment: I have faced the same problem. But I use the annotation `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`. And I also want to solve this problem using JPA framework.